# WCF calls fails silently sometimes

Tags: .net, wcf

I implemented an **one way wcf method**. I followed the way mentioned in this article to handle the webservice call [article](http://http://web.archive.org/web/20080803051143/www.iserviceoriented.com/blog/post/Indisposable+-+WCF+Gotcha+1.aspx) I use this below class to call the web service.

```
public delegate void UseServiceDelegate<T>(T proxy);

public static class Service<T>
{
    public static ChannelFactory<T> _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>("*"); 

    public static void Use(UseServiceDelegate<T> codeBlock)
    {
        IClientChannel proxy = (IClientChannel)_channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            codeBlock((T)proxy);
            proxy.Close();
            success = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!success)
            {
                proxy.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}

Service<IOrderService>.Use(orderService=>
{
  orderService.PlaceOrder(request);
}
```

When we moved the code to the production, sometimes the wcf call fails without giving any error message and sometimes it works without any problem. I have the service and client in the same application.

Any help much appreciated.

My Interface:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
public interface IOrderService
{
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void PlaceOrder(OrderRequest request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [configure tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and see if there's anything descriptive in the output using the [service trace viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Add a catch block in your try statement and at least log the message if you do not want to handle the errors here.

```
    catch (Exception ex0)
    {
        // Log exception here
        throw; // will rethrow the same exception to outside
    }
```

this way at least you will have a log for the exceptions if you missed/forgot handling it

Comment: I have try/catch block implemented where I call this Service.

Comment: What about the logs that you write in this try catch block, isn't it pinpointing to the cause of the silent failures?

Comment: There is no exception thrown at all, we couldn't able to find any errors. :(

There could be lot concurrent requests from different users. Some of them gets ignored I think..